# rsync only folders and files in special sub directory

Tags: rsync

I have the following structure

[image]

I want to copy only folders, subfolders and files, which are located in "_bearbeitet".

I am trying it with the following options

```
--archive --hard-links --ignore-errors --force --exclude=* --include=/_bearbeitet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your rules in the wrong order, and your glob is too general.

Try this:

```
--include=/_bearbeitet --exclude='/*'
```

So altogether:

```
rsync -aH --ignore-errors --force --include=/_bearbeitet --exclude='/*' $src $dest
```

The rule is that, for each file, rsync will use the *first* include/exclude rule that matches, and will include anything that matches no rule.

So, first list what you want to include: `/_barbeitet` matches the named directory at the top level only.

Then list what you want to exclude after: `/*` matches all files and directories at the top level only. Note that `*` on it's own would *exclude all* files and directories *anywhere*, including files and directories inside an explicitly included directory.

You should also take care to put quotes around `*` in patterns or else the shell will expand them before calling rsync, which is not what you want.